# double integral $e^{-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: calculus

Given
$$\iint\limits_{R}e ^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$
for $R=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \le 9\}$.  Is it $$ \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{3}e ^{-r^2} r dr d \theta$$

Comment: Yes it is. $ $ $ $

Comment: As I recall the $dxdy$ changes to $rdrd\theta$ in polar. So shouldn't there be an extra factor of $r$ in the transformed integral? If so that would mean one could substitute say $w=-r^2$ and make headway...

Comment: is the answer pi- pi/(e^9)

Comment: You need to be very careful with missing the $dx$, $dy$, $dr$ and $d\theta$ in your integrals!

Comment: Actually the outside integral goes to $2\pi$ so I'm getting $2\pi(1-e^{-9})$, i.e. twice your answer.

Comment: @coffeemath But does the inner integral equal $(1-e^{-9})$ or $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-9})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're asking whether
$$
\int \text{d}x\int \text{d}y\ e^{-x^2-y^2} = \int_0^{2\pi}\text{d}\phi\int_0^3\text{d}r\ e^{-r^2}\ ,
$$
where the first integral is restricted to $x^2+y^2\leq9$.
The answer is 'no', as $\text{d}x\text{d}y=r\text{d}r\text{d}\phi$, so you need a further factor $r$ on the right-hand-side.

Comment: yes i forgot to add r, but I get some weird answer like pi-(pi/e^9)